# How do you set a text value in FastReport

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, fastreport

Language is C# for an MVC4 web application

I'm using the FastReport.Net Demo.

I set a text field and named it InvNo.
I created a Parameter and named it InvNoVal and assigned that to the text value for InvNo.

here is my serverside code

```
WebReport invrpt = new WebReport();
invrpt.Width = 600;
invrpt.Height = 800;
invrpt.ReportFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/SubscriberInvoice.frx");
invrpt.Report.SetParameterValue("InvNoVal", "12");
invrpt.Report.Prepare();
invrpt.ToolbarIconsStyle = ToolbarIconsStyle.Black;
ViewBag.WebReport = invrpt;
return View("SubInvoice");
```

but when I run it I get a StackOverflowException in the mscorlib

Comment: Is your question about how to do something, or why you're getting an error?

Comment: Both,  either I don't know how to do what I'm trying to do, (which I don't) or the error is preventing me.

Comment: Why do you think the stack overflow is related to setting a text value?

Comment: only time I get it is after this line runs.  "invrpt.Report.SetParameterValue("InvNoVal", "12");".  If I comment that line out, it runs ok, but obviously the report isn't what I want

Comment: Where is the code that moves `InvNoVal` into `InvNo`?

Comment: Thats static, its done in FastReportDesign

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963036/why-is-fast-report-vcl-in-delphi-raising-a-stack-overflow-exception-when-editing .. Seems like FastReport is not exactly... robust, when handling parameters/variables.  Check the way you're passing in values.  Make sure you're not "crossing types..." strings vs. numbers, etc.

Comment: That's Delphi code, the .net version doesn't have a Variable object.  Its pretty obvious I don't know what I'm doing, just started playing with it today and I suspect I'm using the wrong function or I've not initialized something like I should

Comment: Regardless, it should be giving you a better error message than this.  Make sure you have the latest version of FastReport.  Some stack overflow errors were solved in updates.

Comment: downloaded it last night.  Could it be that I've not initialized a dataset for this report.  I just created a parameter and am trying to use that.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late answer, but I just got a stackoverflow exception in FastReports.

I had a subreport, and I've set it's property PrintOnParent to true. That solved it.

Comment: Dino,  thanks for the tip, but I started using Stimulsoft.  Their support is more responsive.